# What happens to the lookup in a Hashmap or Hashset when the objects Hashcode changes

Tags: java, hash, hashmap, hashcode, hashset

In a Hashmap the hash code of the key provided is used to place the value in the hashtable. In a Hashset the obects hashcode is used to place the value in the underlying hashtable. i.e the advantage of the hashmap is that you have the flexibility of deciding what you want as the key so you can do nice things like this.

```
Map<String,Player> players = new HashMap<String,Player>();
```

This can map a string such as the players name to a player itself.

My question is is what happens to to the lookup when the key's Hashcode changes.

This i expect isn't such a major concern for a Hashmap as I wouldn't expect nor want the key to change. In the previous example if the players name changes he is no longer that player. However I can look a player up using the key change other fields that aren't the name and future lookups will work.

However in a Hashset since the entire object's hashcode is used to place the item if someone slightly changes an object future lookups of that object will no longer resolve to the same position in the Hashtable since it relies on the entire objects Hashcode. Does this mean that once data is in a Hashset it shouldnt be changed. Or does it need to be rehashed? or is it done automatically etc? What is going on?

Comment: I'm made a lot of statements/assumptions in this question please let me know if any are wrong

Answer (score 21, accepted):

In your example, a String is immutable so its hashcode cannot change.  But hypothetically, if the hashcode of an object did change while was a key in a hash table, then it would *probably disappear* as far as hashtable lookups were concerned.  I went into more detail in this Answer to a related question:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/13114376/139985 .  (The original question is about a `HashSet`, but a `HashSet` is really a `HashMap` under the covers, so the answer covers this case too.)

It is safe to say that if the keys of either a HashMap or a TreeMap are mutated in a way that affects their respective `hashcode()` / `equals(Object)` or `compare(...)` or `compareTo(...)` contracts, then the data structure will "break".

---

> Does this mean that once data is in a Hashset it shouldn't be changed.

Yes.

> Or does it need to be rehashed? or is it done automatically etc?

It won't be automatically rehashed.  The `HashMap` won't notice that the hashcode of a key has changed.  Indeed, you won't even get recomputation of the hashcode when the `HashMap` resizes.  The data structure *remembers* the original hashcode value to avoid having to recalculate all of the hashcodes when the hash table resizes.

If you know that the hashcode of a key is going to change you need to remove the entry from the table BEFORE you mutate the key, and add it back afterwards.  (If you try to `remove` / `put` it after mutating the key, the chances are that the `remove` will fail to find the entry.)

> What is going on?

What is going on is that you violated the contract.  Don't do that!

The contract consists of two things:

1. The standard hashcode / equals contract as specified in the [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Object.html) for `Object`.
2. An additional constraint that an object's hashcode must not change while it is a key in a hash table.

The latter constraint is not stated specifically in the `HashMap` [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/HashMap.html), but the [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Map.html) for `Map` says this:

> *Note: great care must be exercised if mutable objects are used as map keys. The behavior of a map is not specified if the value of an object is changed in a manner that affects `equals` comparisons while the object is a key in the map.*

A change that affects equality (typically) also affects the hashcode.  At the implementation level, if a `HashMap` entry's key's hashcode changes, the entry will typically *now* be in the wrong hash bucket and will be invisible to `HashMap` methods that perform lookups.

Comment: Can you explain one thing though?
If I change some field (for example int 10 became 5) which is used in hashcode calculation.
Then we won't be able to find value in the map, because it uses old version of the key. So hash codes are different, right?

But how this violates the contract with equals? Equals as far as I understand still will work properly, because it checks the same fields.

Can you explain please?

Comment: 1)  Yes.  2) It violates the contract because *part of the contract* says that you should make a change to a key object that changes its hashcode while it is in a hashmap.  The fact that equals still works is beside the point.  The real problem is that the entry in the hashmap will be on the wrong hash chain, so lookup won't find it.

Answer (score 3):

In your example, the keys are String which are immutable. So the hashcode of the keys won't change. What happens when the hashcode of the keys changes is undefined and leads to "weird" behaviour. See the example below, which prints 1, false and 2. The object remains in the set, but the set looks like it is broken (contains returns false).

Extract from [Set's javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Set.html):

> Note: Great care must be exercised if mutable objects are used as set elements. The behavior of a set is not specified if the value of an object is changed in a manner that affects equals comparisons while the object is an element in the set. A special case of this prohibition is that it is not permissible for a set to contain itself as an element.

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    Set<MyObject> set = new HashSet<>();
    MyObject o1 = new MyObject(1);
    set.add(o1);
    o1.i = 2;
    System.out.println(set.size());       //1
    System.out.println(set.contains(o1)); //false
    for (MyObject o : set) {
        System.out.println(o.i);          //2
    }
}

private static class MyObject {
    private int i;

    public MyObject(int i) {
        this.i = i;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return i;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (obj == null) return false;
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass()) return false;
        final MyObject other = (MyObject) obj;
        if (this.i != other.i) return false;
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Ok so to summarise.

The Key for a hashmap should never change?

And any object to be put in a hashset should be immutable?

Comment: @Luke1111 Yes, unless you want to create that weird behaviour on purpose - I can't think of one to be honest.

Answer (score 0):

The `HashSet` is backed up by a `HashMap`.

From the **javadocs**.

> This class implements the Set interface, backed by a hash table
>   (actually a HashMap instance).

So if you **change** the hashcode, I doubt whether you can access the object.

### Internal Implementation Details

The `add` implementation of `HashSet` is

```
 public boolean add(E e) {
        return map.put(e, PRESENT)==null;
 }
```

The key is the elem and value is just a dummy Object called PRESENT

and the `contains` implementation is

```
public boolean contains(Object o) {
        return map.containsKey(o);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

With Java's hashes, the original reference is simply not found. It's searched in the bucket corresponding the current hashcode, and not found.

To recover from this after the fact, the Hash keySet must be iterated over, and and any key which is not found by `contains` method must be removed through the iterator. Preferable is to remove the key from the map, then store the value with new key.