# Replace HashSet contents without creating new HashSet Object

Tags: java, collections, hashset

I have to manipulate strings present under a big HashSet Object
  and I would like to know if there is any possibility of manipulating existing 
  HashSet object with out creating a new HashSet object

Below is my current logic, in which, I wanted to avoid the creation of 2nd HashSet (`set2` object).

```
HashSet<String> set1 = new HashSet<String>();
set1.add("AB.12");
set1.add("CD.34");
set1.add("EF.56");
set1.add("GH.78");

HashSet<String> set2 = new HashSet<String>();
for(String data : set1) {
    set2.add(data.substring(0,2));
}
```

**P.S.: The reason for going for a Set is to avoid duplicate entries (come from different source).**

Comment: what manipulation you intent to do ?

Comment: "AB.12" and "AB" are two different object, do you want to keep the original object?

Comment: I wanted to keep "AB" into my set.

Comment: One approach is to store not a plain `String`, but a _data structure_ like `{AB.12, int fromIndex, int toIndex}` in your original `HashSet`.

Comment: Is there a specific reason to avoid the creation of the second hashset? If it is just a memory issue then the answer by @KishoreReddy will address that concern. Otherwise with non-list collections there is no way to both insert and remove elements in the same process.

Answer (score 3):

Elements in a HashSet should not be altered to maintain the integrity of the set. You can think of them as immutable elements.

And since the order of a HashSet is not defined or constant over time, it won't be possible to add and remove elements simultaneously without potentially colliding with new elements.

However, if you're trying to conserve memory, you can simultaneously remove from set1 and add to set2.

```
Iterator iter = set1.iterator();

while(iter.hasNext()){
    set2.add(iter.next().substring(0, 2));
    iterator.remove();
}
```

Comment: Will the memory be re-claimed immediately after removing the elements? or will he have to wait for GC to kick in?

Comment: *"Elements in a HashSet are immutable."* No, not necessarily.

Comment: You'll have to wait for GC to kick it. It'll be reclaimed ASAP, but not immediately.

Comment: @Tom *primitive types* in a HashSet are immutable. My apologies.

Comment: That is also wrong, because you can't place primitive types into a HashSet :P. I guess you mean what `String` is immutable and/or that `HashSet` items should be immutable to maintain a correct hash value. This would be true :).

Comment: @Tom, you are so much better with words that I am! I'll edit my answer to state that.

Answer (score 1):

Java `Set` does not provide ordered access so you cannot step through one by one to do a replacement.

With a `List`, you could do:

```
for (int i = 0; i < list.count(); i++) {

    list.set(i, list.get(i).substring(0, 2));
}
```

Note that building a new `Set` object is not a problem, unless you have a massive data-set.

---

Another option is to use a `Stack`:

```
final Stack<String> toProcess = new Stack<>();

for (final String i : set1) {

    toProcess.push(i);
}

set1.clear();

while (!toProcess.isEmpty()) {

    set1.add(toProcess.pop().substring(0, 2));
}
```

Comment: I know this already, as I already have mentioned in my query, I have huge data.

Comment: Added another option; but I still think that `List` will be easier. Sometimes you have to relax your design for efficiency reasons.

Answer (score 1):

If you really thinking about wastage of memory then you can do like :

```
   HashSet<String> set2 = new HashSet<String>();

   Iterator<String> ite = set1.iterator();
   while(ite.hasNext()){
         String data = ite.next();
         ite.remove(); //look this
        set2.add(data.substring(0,2));
   }
```

Comment: OP wants to avoid creating another set entirely

Answer (score 1):

There isn't a perfect solution to your problem. The issue is that a `Set` by definition does not allow indexing. Coupled with the fact that `String` is immutable, modifying the data is not feasible.

I think you should consider changing 2 things.

1. Use a data structure that allows you to replace elements (such as a `List`)

<s>2. Use a mutable datatype, possibly creating your own class as the data type element (as Victor suggested in the comments).</s>

This will break the internals of the HashSet because the index was created by hashing the element, if the element changes, it may disappear.

Comment: I would advice against #2. What would the `equals` and `hashCode` implementations be for the mutable class?

Comment: He could create a wrapper class for String and use the java implementations. Modifying the object would be as simple as re-assigning the String field. Or, he could roll his own string class of char[] (which is better since it appears he is concerned about memory usage)

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13177124/what-happens-to-the-lookup-in-a-hashmap-or-hashset-when-the-objects-hashcode-cha

Comment: You are right. I forgot about indexing based on the hash.

Comment: *"This will break the internals of the HashSet"* You are right: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4718009/mutable-objects-and-hashcode