# HashSet duplicate behaviour

Tags: java, duplicates, hashset

I have two **`Person`** objects with same data in `HasSet` but I am still getting duplicates. Here is the scenario.

```
class Person {

private String fName;
private String lName;

Person(String fName, String lName){
    this.fName = fName;
    this.lName = lName;
}

//getters & setters

@Override
public int hashCode() {
    return (int) fName.hashCode() * lName.hashCode();
}

@Override
public boolean equals(Object o) {
    if(o == null) return false;
    if(!(o instanceof Person)) return false;

    Person  other = (Person) o;
    if(!this.fName.equals(other.fName)) return false;
    if(!this.lName.equals(other.lName)) return false;

    return true;
}
}

public class HashSetDuplicateTest {
public static void main(String[] args){
    Set<Person> pSet = new HashSet<Person>();

    Person p1 = new Person("abc", "efg");
    pSet.add(p1);
    p1.setlName("xyz");

    Person p2 = new Person("abc", "xyz");
    pSet.add(p2);

    for(Person p : pSet){
            System.out.println(p.getfName()+" "+p.getlName());
    }
}
}

Output:
"abc xyz"
"abc xyz"
```

any idea on this behavior of `HashSet` ?? As you have seen, I have two `Person` objects with same data in HasSet but still getting duplicates.

Comment: You're modifying objects after you've added them to the `HashSet`. You can't do that. See the [Javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Set.html) or [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13114043/java-hashset-contains-duplicates-if-contained-element-is-modified) very similar (duplicate?) question: "The behavior of a set is not specified if the value of an object is changed in a manner that affects equals comparisons while the object is an element in the set."

Comment: don't look what java says...why set in java doing like this...what is the reason behind it...the question is this here?

Answer (score 1):

```
Person p1 = new Person("abc", "efg");
pSet.add(p1);
p1.setlName("xyz");
```

HashSet elements (just like HashMap keys) are supposed to be immutable.

If you update them (in ways that affect `equals` or `hashCode`), then things break.

In this particular case, you end up with a Person in a hash bucket that does not match its hash code anymore, so that it will not be found when inserting potential new elements (and checking for duplicates). It will still be returned when iterating over all elements (so that it does show up in the printout).

Comment: I know that Map keys should be immutable. But HashSet internally use HashMap and store elements (like Person objects here) as Keys in Map. And Map keys can't be same. How HashMap storing the 2 same keys here as Person objects.

Comment: HashSet just uses the Person object as a Key for a HashMap (the value is a dummy placeholder). So if you understand why your changing Person won't work as a HashMap key, that is the root problem here.

Comment: @YTyagi HashMaps are *completely broken* if your keys can change. Storing two identical elements is a valid kind of "completely broken".

Comment: As Java says "The behavior of a set is not specified if the value of an object is changed in a manner that affects equals comparisons while the object is an element in the set"... its understandable, we are going against it..... but why its happening like that..any concrete reason? ..the first element changed same to second before adding the second, so it should update the existing one, instead of adding...

Comment: Elements are placed into hash buckets according to their hashcode on insertion. If you later change the hashcode, it will still be in the original bucket. Thus, it won't be found when the second element is added, and cannot be replaced.