# Set can contain duplicates?

Tags: java, set, duplicates, equals

**UPDATE: The answer is actually in the documentation:**

> Note: Great care must be exercised if mutable objects are used as set
>   elements. The behavior of a set is not specified if the value of an
>   object is changed in a manner that affects equals comparisons while
>   the object is an element in the set.

**Case closed, thanks everyone!**

Edit: The referenced topic about duplicates in a hash sets does have the same point, however it does not answer my question: Why is the documentation not saying anything about that a set is only guaraneteed to work with immutable objects?

edit2: I do understand what happens. The set of course cannot know when the hashcode of the entities change after they have been added. But the point is that imo the documentation should clearly state that sets only work properly with immutable objects.

I've been working with Java for more than 5 years now, and don't laugh, but only now I realized something about the Sets. I thought I understood what a set is, namely what the doc says:

> A collection that contains no duplicate elements.  More formally, sets
>   * contain no pair of elements `e1` and `e2` such that  * `e1.equals(e2)`, and at most one null element.

But, this is totally not true?! See here:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

        Set<Entity> entitySet = new HashSet<>();
        Entity e1 = new Entity("One");
        Entity e2 = new Entity("Two");
        entitySet.add(e1);
        entitySet.add(e2);

        e2.name = "One"; // !
        System.out.println("Objects equal:" + e1.equals(e2));

        Iterator<Entity> iterator = entitySet.iterator();
        while (iterator.hasNext()) {
            System.out.println(iterator.next());
        }
    }

    static class Entity {

        String name;

        Entity(String name) {
            this.name = name;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean equals(Object obj) {
            if (!(obj instanceof Entity)) {
                return false;
            }
            return name.equals(((Entity) obj).name);
        }

        @Override
        public int hashCode() {
            return name.hashCode();
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "Entity[name=" + name + "]";
        }
```

Output:

```
Objects equal:true
Entity[name=One]
Entity[name=One]
```

So, I guess the thing about sets not containing duplicates is only true when we deal with immutable entries? But why is the doc not saying anything about it? I was never really aware of this. The problem with this of course is that the entites could contain any number of further fields that are not part of the equality definition; and they might be different in those fields. I'm thinking about something like this:

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {

        Set<Entity> entitySet = new HashSet<>();
        Entity e1 = new Entity("Public", true);
        Entity e2 = new Entity("Secret", false);
        entitySet.add(e1);
        entitySet.add(e2);
        e2.name = "Public";

        Iterator<Entity> iterator = entitySet.iterator();
        // print only public entity (e1)
        while (iterator.hasNext()) {
            Entity e = iterator.next();
            if (e.equals(e1)) { 
                System.out.println(e);
            }
        }
    }

    static class Entity {

        String name;
        boolean mayBeDisplayedToUser;

        Entity(String name, boolean mayBeDisplayedToUser) {
            this.name = name;
            this.mayBeDisplayedToUser = mayBeDisplayedToUser;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean equals(Object obj) {
            if (!(obj instanceof Entity)) {
                return false;
            }
            return name.equals(((Entity) obj).name);
        }

        @Override
        public int hashCode() {
            return name.hashCode();
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "Entity[name=" + name + ", may be displayed:" + mayBeDisplayedToUser + "]";
        }
    }
```

Output:

> Entity[name=Public, may be displayed:false] Entity[name=Public, may be
>   displayed:true]

So.. I'm quite puzzled right now. Am I the only one that was not aware of this?

Comment: Are we sure that by equals the set doesn't perform '==' indicating two variables pointed at the same object? This would allow for the cases you presented.

Comment: I don't know. He overrides both the equals AND the hashCode. I am guessing the contract was broken somewhere here...

Comment: I adhere to the contract of hashcode and equals. if my entities are equal, then they have the same hashcode. I just delegate both methods to the "name" variable. So as long as we assume that the String class implements these methods correctly, then it should work imo.

Comment: The hashcode is only created and tested at the point that you add the item to the HashSet. Subisquent changes that you make to an object will not result in the hashcode being recalculated.

Answer (score 5):

You are adding the items to the `HashSet` while they are unique and then mutating the items after the fact. The containing `HashSet` has no idea that you broke the set contract by changing `obj.name`.

Comment: Ah yeah you are right. The situation is described here for further reading. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13114043/java-hashset-contains-duplicates-if-contained-element-is-modified

Comment: I understand the behaviour. I think I got my question around wrong. My question is why this problem with mutable elements is not stated in the doc, and if people are aware of this

Comment: ah, thanks @Locke. So actually it is described in the documentation. So I guess I never read that properly.. Ok thank you, case closed :)

Comment: Hey @user3237736 you should either accept an existing answer or write your own answer and accept it if your problem is resolved.